# Is it possible to abandon/abort a RadAjaxRequest that is still processing when a new request is made?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, telerik, radajaxmanager

I've got a C# web application that presents the user with reports, occasionaly the reports take in the neighbourhood of several minutes to generate (instead of a few seconds).

I have a `RadTreeView` of "`ReportType`" links, when clicked executes a `RadAjaxRequest` using the `RadAjaxManager` from the client-side.

```
function RadTreeviewNodeClicked(sender, eventArgs) {
            try {
                console.log("fired again: " + eventArgs.get_node().get_text());
                var radAjaxManager = $find("<%= RadAjaxManager.GetCurrent(Page).ClientID %>");
                radAjaxManager.ajaxRequest("NodeClicked");
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("error on nodeclicked");
            }
        }

 //from my pageload
 radAjaxManager1 = RadAjaxManager.GetCurrent(Page);
 radAjaxManager1.AjaxRequest += RadAjaxManager1_AjaxRequest;
 radAjaxManager1.ResponseScripts.Add("AttachJQueryUIDateTimePickers();");
 radAjaxManager1.AjaxSettings.AddAjaxSetting(radAjaxManager1,pnlRightContent,RadAjaxLoadingPanel1);
 radAjaxManager1.ClientEvents.OnResponseEnd = "ResponseEnd";
```

The `ajaxRequest` handler on the server loads up the appropriate report for the link that was clicked and displays it on the right hand side in an asp:panel.   The menu and panel are both wrapped in a `RadAjaxPanel`.

If the report data is still loading (the stored procedure is executing) and a user clicks another link:

- the client event is triggered
- the server finishes the first event
- the respondeEnd event is fired
- the server starts processing the 2nd event

I would like to abandon/abort the first event when a subsequent event is clicked.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out it's possible with Telerik, by setting the Queue Size of the rad Ajax Manager to 0:

```
        radAjaxManager1.RequestQueueSize = 0;
```

Comment: My page had RadAjaxManagerProxy, didn't see the property there.  I found it on RadAjaxPanel I was using, but setting it to 0 didn't cancel the ajax request for me.  It still seems to still wait for it to come back before it processes my redirect